# Why is this a Not a legal OleAut date with a TimeSpan of 100 hours and 100 minutes

Tags: c#, date, datetime, ole

I'm trying to create a date from a `TimeSpan` that has 100 hours and 100 minutes but i'm gettin the error:

> Run-time exception (line 9): Not a legal OleAut date.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [System.OverflowException: Not a legal OleAut date.]    at
>   System.DateTime.TicksToOADate(Int64 value)

```java
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(100) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
        var OADate = DateTime.FromOADate((DateTime.MinValue.AddTicks(timeSpan.Ticks)).ToOADate());

    }
}
```

This is to link in with a legacy value in the db from vb6.

It works with small hour and minutes values but fails with this, any ideas?

Created a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dEttD1)

Comment: Seems like the TimeSpan cannot total 24 hours or over

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's have a look at the date you are trying to convert into `OADate`:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(100) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);

var OADate = DateTime.MinValue.AddTicks(timeSpan.Ticks);

Console.WriteLine(OADate.ToString("d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

You'll get this

```
5 January 0001 05:40:00
```

But according to the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.8) (**bold** is mine)

> The base OLE Automation Date is midnight, 30 December 1899. The
>   **minimum** OLE Automation date is **midnight, 1 January 0100**. The maximum OLE Automation Date is the same as DateTime.MaxValue, the last
>   moment of 31 December 9999.

that's why `DateTime.MinValue.AddTicks(timeSpan.Ticks).ToOADate()` is *illegal* (OADate is *below the minimum*) and you have the exception thrown.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why i can use DateTime.MinValue and DateTime.MaxValue but i can't use DateTime.MinValue + MyTimeValue?

Comment: @Dezza: you *can* perform `DateTime.MinValue + MyTimeValue` (you'll have a valid `DateTime`), but you *can't* convert this date into *Ole Automatition*

Comment: Yes i just learned that it's because DateTime.MinValue is allowed then anything after that has to be greater than the base date

Comment: @Dezza: yes it will be greater (`5 Jan 0001`), but not *great enough* (1 Jan 0100) to be valid OAdate